# Postgres SQL performance ceiling

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, datagrip

I have a flat table with ~4M rows and a multiindex on 5 columns. Simple select statements which return ~150 rows x 5 columns take roughly 700ms.
I use all 5 multiindex columns in the where filter (in the same order as they're defined in the index itself).

Is this the ceiling of postgres? The query time is acceptably low, but I'd want to make it even lower if possible. Vacuuming does not help (autovacuum takes care of it anyhow with 1000+ runs in the last 2 months).

Explain Plan returns:

```
Index Scan using agg_data_level_idx on agg_data_level  (cost=0.56..8.58 rows=1 width=25)
```

Explain (analyze, buffers, format text) returns:

```
explain (analyze, buffers, format text) select planning_group_name, phone, email, chat from agg_data_level
where planning_group_name = 'French'
and region_name = 'Europe'
and country_name = 'Russia'
and business_name = 'Main'
and schedule_day_lcl_skey = '20191128';
```

Returns

```
Index Scan using agg_data_level_idx on agg_data_level  (cost=0.56..8.58 rows=1 width=25) (actual time=0.051..0.287 rows=144 loops=1)
  Index Cond: (((planning_group_name)::text = 'French'::text) AND (schedule_day_lcl_skey = 20191128) AND ((region_name)::text = 'Europe'::text) AND ((country_name)::text = 'Russia'::text) AND ((business_name)::text = 'Main'::text))
  Buffers: shared hit=16
Planning time: 0.083 ms
Execution time: 0.309 ms
```

Comment: The query takes less the 0.5 milliseconds...

Comment: Apologies if I'm misinterpreting something here: I'm using datagrip, and the services tab returns a time after each query - this one is always around 700ms. The console itself, shows yet another number: [2019-11-29 14:41:59] 144 rows retrieved starting from 1 in 129 ms (execution: 117 ms, fetching: 12 ms)

Comment: The overhead in runtime is clearly caused by DataGrip or the network - not by Postgres. The execution plan shows the execution time on the server without any network roundtrips or the time it takes for the client to retrieve, process and display the data

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in this query time there is not **clear query** only

What is also included:

```
- DataGrip operations like fetching etc.
- JDBC Driver's operations
- Network time
```